# How to handle Azure Storage TableOperation errors in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, error-handling, azure-storage

Once in a while I get the following error when I try to insert data in Azure table storage.

```
Exception calling "Execute" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict."
```

Theoretically this could happen when I insert data with a partition key and row key that already exists.

Because I use ticks (one tick is one ten-millionth of a second) for both partition key and row key I don't think this should be the case. Example below.

But anyway, how can I prevent the exception on `CloudTable.Execute`? Because I have set `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` it will stop my install script. I don't think I can use `-ErrorAction Ignore`?

```
function Corax-Create-Table($tablename)
{
    $context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $g_storage_account_name -StorageAccountKey $g_storage_account_key
    $table = Get-AzureStorageTable $tablename -Context $context
    if ($table -eq $null)
    {
        New-AzureStorageTable $tablename -Context $context
    }
    return $table
}

function Corax-Storage-Insert-Message($table, [String]$partitionKey, [String]$rowKey, [String]$category, [String]$level, [String]$message)
{
    $entity = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity" $partitionKey, $rowKey
    $entity.Properties.Add("Category", $category)
    $entity.Properties.Add("Level", $level)
    $entity.Properties.Add("Message", $message)
    $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::Insert($entity))
}

$session = $(Get-Date).Ticks

$t = Corax-Create-Table('test')
Corax-Storage-Insert-Message $t $session $(Get-Date).Ticks "Database" "Progress" "Database table 1 is updated"
Corax-Storage-Insert-Message $t $session $(Get-Date).Ticks "Database" "Progress" "Database table 2 is updated"
Corax-Storage-Insert-Message $t $session $(Get-Date).Ticks "Database" "Progress" "Database table 3 is updated"
Corax-Storage-Insert-Message $t $session $(Get-Date).Ticks "Database" "Progress" "Database table 4 is updated"
Corax-Storage-Insert-Message $t $session $(Get-Date).Ticks "Database" "Progress" "Database table 5 is updated"
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use Fiddler to see the actual requests going to Azure Storage Table service and confirm what PK/RK combinations you are using?

Comment: Good idea, but this happens only once in a while at a customer site so this is not a viable option.

Comment: Then would it be possible to enable Azure Storage Analytics logging  (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitor-storage-account/) and see the failing requests by analyzing those logs?

Comment: Thanks, I have enabled the logging.

Comment: But, back to the original question: is there a way to catch the `CloudTable.Execute` exception?

Answer (score 0):

Did you you try `try/catch`?

```powershell
function Corax-Storage-Insert-Message($table, [String]$partitionKey, [String]$rowKey, [String]$category, [String]$level, [String]$message)
{
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    try{
        $entity = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity" $partitionKey, $rowKey
        $entity.Properties.Add("Category", $category)
        $entity.Properties.Add("Level", $level)
        $entity.Properties.Add("Message", $message)
        $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::Insert($entity))
    }
    catch{      
        ## error handling code      
    }
}
```

In the catch you could log the error or execute your call again with an incremented key:

```powershell
Corax-Storage-Insert-Message $table $partitionKey [String]([int]$rowKey + 1) $category $level $message
```